# Criação de Pastas Recursivas

Tags: php, diretório

### O Problema:

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira mais prática do que utilizar as estruturas de controle `IF/ELSE` para criação de pastas recursivamente, baseado nos inputs que o usuário digitou.

## Contexto:

Por exemplo, no meu script, eu recebo os dados, valido e sanitizo os posteriormente, e então eu crio pastas com os dados do campos informados, até ai tudo bem, mas o problema é que alguns campos não são obrigatórios de serem digitados, portanto se eu tiver, por exemplo 4 campos:
 *Nome*, *Empresa*, *Cidade*, *Estado*
Eu gostaria de saber se existe outra maneira além do `IF/ELSE`:

```
$dir = "uploads/{$nome}/{$empresa}/{$cidade}/{$estado}/";       
    if(!is_dir($dir)):
            mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    endif;
```

De criar as pastas com os dados que foram digitados, ignorando os campos vazios para evitar erros

Comment: E o que deve acontecer se houver algum campo vazio?

Comment: Ele deve ignorar o campo da variável $dir, caso o campo nome esteja vazio: `$dir="uploads/{$empresa}/{$cidade}/{$estado}/";` e assim sucessivamente até verificar todos campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira prática (poucas linhas) é criar um vetor com os valores das variáveis e filtrá-los com a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php). Depois, pode unificar os valores restantes com a função [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php). Veja o exemplo:

```
$nome    = "";
$empresa = "";
$cidade  = "foo";
$estado  = "bar";

$dir = 'uploads/' . implode('/', array_filter([$nome, $empresa, $cidade, $estado]));

var_dump($dir); // string(15) "uploads/foo/bar"
```

Como nativamente uma string vazia é analisada como falso pelo PHP, a função `array_filter` elimina todos os valores vazios, depois os restantes são concatenados através da função `implode`.

Pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/Gsp9/0) ou [aqui](https://ideone.com/iSLpBr).